# A rule to transpose pattern and target of a rule?

Tags: rule

I am trying to write a Mathematica function that will take a rule such as 
`a->b` to `b->a'. Can this be done?

Comment: `Reverse@Rule[a, b]`

Answer (score 3):

Use a pattern to deconstruct the `Rule`, and reconstitute it backwards in your function body.

```
f[Rule[a_, b_]] := Rule[b, a]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a -> b // Reverse
```

Or

```
(a -> b)[[{2, 1}]]
```

Or

```
 a -> b /. (x_ -> y_) -> y -> x
```

Comment: The first one is cleanest